# A property of positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Suppose that we have some real numbers $b_\alpha\in \mathbb{R},\ \alpha=1,\cdots,s.$

And let $A=(a_{ij})\in M_{s}(\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix. Now we define some new numbers $c_\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ as
$$ \begin{equation}\left(\begin{array}{c} c_{1}\\ c_2\\ \vdots\\ c_{s}\end{array}\right)=A\cdot \left(\begin{array}{c} b_{1}\\ b_2\\ \vdots\\ b_{s}\end{array}\right).\end{equation} $$

We can see that $c_\alpha=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^s a_{\alpha j}\cdot b_j,\ \alpha=1,\cdots,s.$ So $c_\alpha$ is the linear combination of $b_\alpha.$

I'm trying to solve a mechanics problem, where $a_\alpha$ and $c_\alpha$ are some coordinates. I want to express each $c_\alpha$ in the following form:
$$c_{\alpha}=\sum_{i=1}^{\alpha} \lambda_ib_i+\sum_{j=\alpha+1}^s \mu_jc_j.$$

Here $\lambda_i,\mu_j $ are some constants determined by matrix $A$ and index $\alpha.$

I find that if matrix $A$ is positive definite, the such expressions really exist. But I don't know why.

**Question:** Prove that if $A$ is a positive definite matrix, then we can always express each $c_\alpha$ as $\displaystyle c_{\alpha}=\sum_{i=1}^{\alpha} \lambda_ib_i+\sum_{j=\alpha+1}^s \mu_jc_j.$

Comment: This should follow from the fact that in a positive definite matrix all the minors along the diagonal are strictly positive. (In essence you are trying to show that $b_1,...,b_\alpha, A b_{\alpha+1},...,A b_s$ is still a basis for any choice of $\alpha$).

Comment: @Sebastian Schoennenbeck: That's it! And I think it should be $b_1,\cdots,b_\alpha,A_{(\alpha+1)}\cdot b,\cdots,A_{(s)}\cdot b.$ Thanks！

Comment: Glad I could help. If you figured it out you should consider writing an answer yourself and accepting it.

Comment: Right. I'll write an answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote  $\mathbf{c}=\left(\begin{array}{c} c_1\\c_2\\ \vdots\\ c_s\end{array}\right), \mathbf b=\left(\begin{array}{c} b_1\\b_2\\ \vdots\\ b_s\end{array}\right),$ then we have $\mathbf c=A\cdot \mathbf b.$

Notice that $c_\alpha=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^s a_{\alpha j}\cdot b_j=A_{(\alpha)}\cdot \mathbf b, \ \alpha=1,\cdots,s,$
So we have

$$\left(\begin{array}{c} b_1\\b_2\\ \vdots\\ b_\alpha\\ c_{\alpha+1}\\c_{\alpha+2}\\  \vdots\\c_s\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} E_{(1)}\\E_{(2)}\\\vdots\\ E_{(\alpha)}\\ A_{(\alpha+1)}\\ A_{(\alpha+2)}\\\vdots\\ A_{(s)}\end{array}\right)\cdot \mathbf b,  $$
Here $E$ is the $s$ identity matrix.
Let $B=\left(\begin{array}{c} E_{(1)}\\E_{(2)}\\\vdots\\ E_{(\alpha)}\\ A_{(\alpha+1)}\\ A_{(\alpha+2)}\\\vdots\\ A_{(s)}\end{array}\right),$ and define orthogonal matrix $I_{\alpha}:=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 0&\cdots&0& 1\\  0&\cdots& 1& 0 \\ \vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\ 1&\cdots&0&0\end{array}\right),$ then we see 
 $$\det B=\det \left(\begin{array}{ccccc} a_{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+1)}&\cdots& a_{(\alpha+1)s}\\a_{(\alpha+2)(\alpha+1)}&\cdots& a_{(\alpha+2)s}\\ \vdots& \ddots &\vdots\\a_{s(\alpha+1)}&\cdots& a_{ss}\end{array}\right)$$$$=\det \bigg[I_{s-\alpha}^T\cdot \left(\begin{array}{ccccc} a_{ss}&a_{s(s-1)}&\cdots& a_{s(\alpha+1)}\\a_{(s-1)s}&a_{(s-1)(s-1)}&\cdots& a_{(s-1)(\alpha+1)}\\ \vdots&\vdots& \ddots &\vdots\\a_{(\alpha+1)s}&a_{(\alpha+1)(s-1)}&\cdots& a_{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+1)}\end{array}\right)\cdot I_{s-\alpha}\bigg]$$
$$=\det  \left(\begin{array}{ccccc} a_{ss}&a_{s(s-1)}&\cdots& a_{s(\alpha+1)}\\a_{(s-1)s}&a_{(s-1)(s-1)}&\cdots& a_{(s-1)(\alpha+1)}\\ \vdots&\vdots& \ddots &\vdots\\a_{(\alpha+1)s}&a_{(\alpha+1)(s-1)}&\cdots& a_{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+1)}\end{array}\right),$$
So $\det B$ equals to the $\alpha$ th principal minor of the matrix $C,$ which is defined as $C:=(a_{(s-i+1),(s-j+1)}).$

Notice that $C=I_s^T\cdot A\cdot I_s,$ thus
if matrix $A$ is positive definite, then $B$ is also positive definite, so $\det B>0.$

Now let $D=A\cdot B^{-1},$ then we have
$$\mathbf c=D\cdot \left(\begin{array}{c} b_1\\b_2\\ \vdots\\ b_\alpha\\ c_{\alpha+1}\\c_{\alpha+2}\\  \vdots\\c_s\end{array}\right),$$
which is what we want to prove.